# Wordpress - change order by on click

Tags: php, wordpress

Considering the following code, I have the loop in my Wordpress blog which will order posts from oldest to newer.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'order'    => 'ASC'
    );
    query_posts( $args );
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content'); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I want is to create two links on which the user clicks and changes this parameter, from older to newer or newer to older.

I thought about using jQuery to achieve this but I don't know exactly how I'll change the PHP code based on which link the user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your sort direction to a parameter, e.g

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'order'    => (isset($_GET['dir']) ? $_GET['dir'] : 'ASC')
        );
        query_posts( $args );
    ?>
```

then you can create a link like:

```
<a href="http:example.com/yourpage.php?dir=DESC">Newest to Oldest</a>
<a href="http:example.com/yourpage.php?dir=ASC">Oldest to Newest</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'm afraid that's not what I'm looking for since I don't want it interfering with the URL, but either way I tried and it isn't working. Maybe something wrongly written in the code? Thanks anyway!

Comment: There was a typo: should have been $_GET instead of $_POST. I'm not sure what you mean my "interfering with the URL". Query strings are the normal way of passing data to PHP programs.

Comment: Alright that worked! Well, my original idea was to kinda refresh the page with the new ascending or descending order but leave the URL untouched. Because what I'm concerned about is that when the user goes and grabs the URL to share, other users who click on it will have that conditional order. Do you understand what I mean? But if you think there's no obvious answer for this case I'll accept your answer because technically it's correct :)

Comment: I understand your concern about users grabbing URLs, but the worst that happens is that the order is not what they want and they have to click the link to get the right one. The only alternative I can think of would be to use Javascript and Ajax to get the new content and replace the existing, but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: I understand. I'll accept your answer now because it works, but I'd like to ask you about this - is there a way to change the php through jQuery?

Comment: Yes. You could write a script to fire when the user clicked a link or button, then either (1) use information from the HTML to rearrange the posts on the page; or (2) use Ajax to call a host PHP routine to retrieve the HTML of the posts in an alternative order and replace the existing HTML.

Comment: I like the (1) option best. How do I pass the information from jQuery to PHP though?

Comment: In option 1, you don't need to talk to PHP. When you generate the HTML, each post is surrounded by some wrapper (usually "article"). Make sure each article has an attribute that gives the value you want to sort on, e.g. classname or a data-xxx attribute. Then your Javascript just needs to collect an array of the articles, figure out what order you want them in, and then use jQuery to move them around (e.g. using after()) accordingly.